# using a variable from Database to specify a URL using jinja

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to define a specific file for a user sample but it doesn't seem to work...
I am making a flask app with cards for users, so I can't define the files in the flask route since the loop for displaying the cards is here.

```
{% for user in all_users %}
      <div class="col-lg-3 userCard box" href="/X">
        <span>{{user.name}} ({{user.gender}})</span>
        <a value="PLAY" onclick="play()" href="#" class="icons-outlined sound"></a>
        <audio id="audio" src="{{url_for('static',filename='/audio/output/Sample_{user.id}.mp3')}}"></audio>
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Two options:
Use:

```
{{url_for('static',filename='/audio/output/Sample_'+user.id|string+'.mp3')}
```